# Error with Java transformer

Tags: java, xml, xslt

i wrote a simple class that reads XML document and transforms it into CSV based on XSL style sheet. This process has been working perfectly for days but now the system crashes when i try the transformation process and it produces this error.

```
   (Location of error unknown)java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Abbeyleefinal.csv (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
at Simplex.simplexTransform(Simplex.java:41)
```

Comment: It's not clear where the c:\Abbeyleefinal.csv appears in your code, but in general most APIs for XML require URIs, not filenames, and what you have supplied is a filename. Some interfaces tolerate filenames even when the documentation says a URI is expected - but not all. In most cases you can convert a filename to a URI by adding "file:///" at the front, though a safer way in Java is `new File(FF).toURI().toString()`.

Comment: i restarted the system and everything became normal.. but how do i implement the approach you just talked about

Comment: You change the code you haven't shown us to do what I said.

Comment: i did what you said by adding ("file:///c:\thefiles\ABBEY\csv6atester.csv)  but it gave me this error   (java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\c:\thefiles\ABBEY\csv6atester.csv (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:84)
 at Simplex.simplexTransform(Simplex.java:41)
)

Comment: You should put "@MichaelKay" in your comment so that he will be notified that you replied to him.

Comment: @Michael Kay am still getting errors.

Comment: It should be forwards slash not backwards slash. If you use File.toURI() it will get it right.

Comment: where exactly do i place the "c:\Abbeyleefinal.csv" file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't understand `C:\` as the beginning of a URI. It's interpreting `C:` as the scheme, analogous to `http:`, when of course you want `C:` to mean drive C.

Try `file:///C:/...` instead.

See also @Michael Kay's comment about using `File.toURI()` to convert a file path to a correct URI.

Comment: The vertical bar for colon was used at one time but is no longer recommended. Use `file:///C:\Abbeyleefinal.csv`.

Comment: @MichaelKay: thanks for the correction. Can you give a reference for why the backslash? E.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx recommends a forward slash.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Should be forwards slash. Use File.toURI() and it will get it right.